# How do I install a generator pass through?

Tags: electrical

I bought a generator for when the commercial power goes out. Rather than run an extension cord from the generator, and through my window into the house; I want to connect an extension cord from the generator, and plug it into an outside junction box (Female plug). Have the outside junction box tie into an internal junction box, with receptacles so I can plug in another inside extension cord to run to my refrigerator and a few lights. What is needed to make this happen? This would be completely separate from the fuse box.

Comment: Are you going to use the regular (15 amp duplex plugs like most things are designed for your home) receptacles or are you going to use the L14-30R plug that comes on some generators?

Answer (score 7):

This is what you would use for a regular house receptacle in the us.

For the outside use a "inlet receptacle"

[image: inlet receptacle]

Then you need a cover for it while not in use.

[image: cover]

Ideally a bubble cover or an in-use cover would be best.  If I find one I'll edit this.

After you get all this and you will need for the inside a cut-in box, receptacle and cover.  A piece of 12/2 romex or NM to go between, wiring the black wire to the brass screws, the white wire to the silver screws and green wire to green screw.

Comment: Excellent advise. This way no one is going to confuse the feed and put power on the grid.

Comment: And costs a lot less than the interlock system and remembering to shut off all unneeded loads so the genset will function.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran cross this.  This gets the power through the outside of the house but have you thought of a transfer panel or using an interlock kit on your panel?  They are pretty cheap and you can get an electrician to install one in about an hour.  Basically you just turn off the breakers in your panel you do not want and everything else has power from your portable generator.  Just don't try to run everything at once!